# php's shell_exec and wget together not working

Tags: php

I am trying to download a URL using `wget` and php's `shell_exec`. However, the result is returning `NULL`. I am on a Windows machine `Cygwin64` installed. The script is as follows:

```
<?php
  $result = shell_exec('C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe' . 'wget' .  escapeshellcmd('https://www.google.com')); 
  var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: insert a blank between bash.exe and wget ... you did it complicated as it is

Comment: It's still NULL after inserting a blank

Comment: update your task pls and post the CMD command which works without using php

Comment: in both cmd and cygwin terminal its 'wget url'

Comment: in command line its working fine